# can't see storyboard in viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

[connect storyboard with ResultViewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpOqm.jpg)

I have set my storyboard's className as ResultViewController, on it there're some labels and buttons

following is it's code, also add another label

```
(void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
   [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
   // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.   }


(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 600, 900)];
     UILabel* chanceLB =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 100, 50, 50)];
     chanceLB.text=@"lalala";
    [self.view addSubview:chanceLB];
    self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
    NSLog(@"this is result view");
```

}

add this ResultViewControllre:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            ResultViewController *resultView=[[ResultViewController alloc]init];
            [self presentViewController:resultView animated:YES completion:nil];

            NSLog(@"count:%lu ",(unsigned long)[[self.view subviews] count]);
        });
```

but i can't see any element on storyboard in the view, only see a "lalala" label and red background, what's more in console, it prints 21, I don't understand why there are 21 subviews since i have only add this resultView on self.view

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're having some constraint issues on your storyboard. Have you added any constraints to the elements on your storyboard? Try this:

- Select an element on your storyboard (Looks like you have a UIButton you could select).
- Go to editor > align > horizontally in container
- Go to editor > align > vertically in container

This should center your element in the view. If this worked then that means that you haven't set any constraints to the elements and are not viewable within the view controller of your storyboard.

For more please read this tutorial:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2][1]